# Does window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString) accept variables for mediaQueryString?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, media-queries

For convenience's sake, I want to build a function that will evaluate and return the result of various media queries. To do so, I've written the following:

```
//Evaluate Media Query
function eMQ(crit) {
    //Build Media Query From Criteria Parameter
    var lMQ = window.matchMedia(crit);
    //Evaluate and Return Result
    if (lMQ.matches) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

I'm wondering if `window.matchMedia(crit)` will correctly use the `crit` string as if the string was explicitly written in.

Quick edit: I thought I should clarify my purpose, considering  the fact that the function above is essentially just `window.matchMedia()` with more steps. I just find `window.matchMedia()` to be unwieldy and would like a shorter version that does not need to include `.matches` on the end.

Comment: yes, yes it would

Answer (score 1):

As long as you pass a valid media query string, your function should work properly, it does not matter if:

- You send that media query to `matchMedia` from a variable.
- You explicitly send a hard-coded media query string to `matchMedia`.

For example:

```
var crit = "(max-width: 700px)";
var lMQ = window.matchMedia(crit);
```

would have the same result as:

```
var lMQ = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
```